# XPATH select only first level children

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the fowoling xml :

```
  <workflow URI=""> 
  <output ID="" URI="#out1"/>  
  <input ID="sessionToken" URI="#sessionToken"/>  
  <services> 
    <sequence> 
      <service URI=""> 
        <input ID="" URI=""/>  
        <input URI="" value=""/>  
        <output ID="" URI=""/> 
      </service> 
    </sequence> 
  </services> 
</workflow>
```

I want to select only the first level children of the workflow node and exclude from this selection the services node, so in my case I would only want

```
 <output ID="" URI="#out1"/>  
 <input ID="sessionToken" URI="#sessionToken"/>
```

this two nodes selected, and I want to use XPATH in java for this. The additional requirments is that the selected node must have the URI parameter.

I have tried this :

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//workflow[@URI='" + oldUrlValue.getNodeValue() + "'] | //workflow//*[not(local-name() = 'services') and @URI]");
```

but I get backall the nodes with URI parameters instead only the main workflow node and the first two children.

I have tried this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean by 'first level children' here, because `services` is located at the same level as `output` and `input` elements. If you mean to return direct child of `workflow` that *do not have any further child element*, then you can use the following XPath expression :

```
//workflow/*[not(*)]
```

Comment: that is what I wanted yes. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Just use the astrik selector (`*`) to select children of the `workflow` node, then only select ones which contain the `URI` attribute (`[@URI]`)

```
//workflow[@URI='" + oldUrlValue.getNodeValue() + "']/*[@URI]
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement:

first level below workflow at any level, and parameter URI

```
String expression = "//workflow/*[@URI]";
```

or first level below workflow at top, and parameter URI

```
String expression = "/workflow/*[@URI]";
```

Or first level below any tag at top and parameter URI

```
String expression = "/*/*[@URI]";
```